# Transpose Country and City in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, transpose

I have a table with 2 fields Country and City. I want to transpose this to I have the Country field as my headers and each of the cities as fields under them.

When I use the code I supplied below I get the results, but with nulls

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Country = 'USA' then City end as USA,
    CASE WHEN Country = 'India' then City end as India,
    CASE WHEN Country = 'UK' then City end as UK
FROM Country
```

[Result from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V57P.jpg)

My question is how do I get a result without nulls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can aggregate these as max(CASE WHEN ... END) AS ....

or you can use pivot:

```
SELECT
    p.* 
FROM 
    Country
    PIVOT (MAX(City) FOR Country IN (USA, India, UK)) P
```

to achieve the result you are looking for, you'll need to introduce a country specific identifier for each city (eg: US: {1: New York, 2: Los Angeles}) like so:

```
select * 
from 
(
     select 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by country order by City, Country) id  
     from Country 
)  c
pivot
(
     max(city) for country in(usa, uk, india)
) p
```

Comment: Both of these only return 1 row of data

Comment: So, you have multiple cities in each country, and would like to generate country name columns with city rows, correct?

Comment: Yes I provided a link to a picture of my current results just under the code. I have 3 cities per country and wish to see all of them. 3 Columns and 3 Rows is my desired output

Comment: Added the necessary changes to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Country = 'USA' then City end) as USA,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Country = 'India' then City end) as India,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Country = 'UK' then City end) as UK
FROM Country
GROUP BY City;
```

Comment: This only returns the first row for me